# Concurrent user and load

Tags: jmeter

By using jmeter, I have 2 task which is :

1. To perform concurrent user load & to see what are the optimum concurrent transactions at any one time for 10,100,300 concurrent user.
2. From each of above, 1ms of data load, 2ms of data load, 3ms of data load

for both, did i just use Synchronizing Timer? what i understand is in Synchronizing Timer, Item (1) is number of simulated user to group by and Item (2) is timeout in ms. Please correct me if Im wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding of the [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) is a little bit wrong.

`Timeout in milliseconds` is not the maximum response time, it's the **maximum** time, JMeter will wait for the `Number of Simultaneous Users to Group by`.

For example you defined 100 threads and one thread fails somewhere prior to the Synchronizing Timer and gets shut down - the Synchronizing Timer will wait **forever** hence your test will never end.

So if you want to set maximum response time threshold so JMeter will automatically mark sampler as failed if the response time exceeds maximum acceptable value - you can do it in 2 ways:

1. Define `Response Timeout` under "Advanced" tab of the [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults)

   [image]
2. Define maximum response time using [Duration Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion)

   [image]

In both cases you will have conditionally failed response in case if response time exceeds i.e. 3 ms

[image]

Comment: Appreciate your reply & thank you so much.. This really solve my confusion.. :)